# apt-get upgrade fails with "Fatal: open /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-20-generic: No such file or directory"

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

This happens on all `apt-get install` and `apt-get upgrade`. Anyone knows what's going on?

```
biran0079@ubunduck:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm7 shim
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.8) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic (4.18.0-25.26~18.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.173.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-25-generic
Warning: /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST1000DM003-1CH162_S1DGBMYR is not on the first disk
Fatal: open /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-20-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware (--configure):
 installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 depends on linux-firmware; however:
  Package linux-firmware is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-hwe-18.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-18.04 depends on linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 (= 4.18.0.25.74); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-hwe-18.04 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-25-generic
Warning: /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST1000DM003-1CH162_S1DGBMYR is not on the first disk
Fatal: open /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-20-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/initramfs/post-update.d//runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic (4.18.0-25.26~18.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-25-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo:
Warning: /dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST1000DM003-1CH162_S1DGBMYR is not on the first disk
Fatal: open /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-20-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-runlilo exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware
 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
 linux-generic-hwe-18.04
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-4.18.0-25-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```